# Discord.py bot reading bold text in messages

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, message, bold

I'm trying to do a simple bot. Whenever someone will say something it will do some stuff.
Its working unless someone uses bold text...

```
    if message.channel.id == 1111111111111111:
        if ("something someone said") in message.content.lower():
#something to do
```

I also tried to use  `if ("**something** someone said") in message.content.lower():` but that doesnt work.

this works when the bold word is at the begining only  `if message.content.startswith('**something** someone said'):`

Same goes to `endswith`

Anyone have any idea why `if ("**something** someone said") in message.content.lower():` doesnt work or have any solution ?

Comment: Have you tried printing out said bold text?

Comment: Could you print the `message.content.lower()`'s result?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace all the `*` characters from the message content

```py
content = message.content.replace("**", "") 
if "something someone said" in content.lower():
    ...
```